# Change kie container / drools engine run-time date dynamically

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor

I have a requirement to run rules(.drl) for user specified date. I have Rules defined with date-effective and date-expires attributes. These rules run as per the server date.

But I would like to run these RULES as per the user specified date with out depending on the server date. Is there a way to set kie container run-time date as we would like to?

```
rule "apply slab"
    agenda-group "calculation"
    date-effective "01-Nov-2019"
    date-expires "01-Dec-2019"
    when
        <condition>
    then
        <business processing logic>
end
```

I need to run the above rule as per use specified date. Let's say today is 
21-Feb-2020 so by default this will not get run but if user wants to validate the rules for November month he should be able to do this irrespective of current date. I mean would like to run the above rule for lets say 01-Nov-2019 irrespective of current date? can I do this ? how ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of such a rule (drl)?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have update the issue with rule sample. Any help is appreciated

Comment: No you can't do that _unless_ you deploy your rules to a server with the date set to your target user's date, which should be totally doable using VMs/containers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never use "date-effective" and "date-expires".

It is easier to add those dates as normal constraints that you are going to compare with a date in one of your pojo (java classe), like effective date, or value date.

So that you can simulate anything you want but entering as input the date you want to use as a reference.

Regards